# Jquery and css click open menu and show active menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am try to make a jquery dropdown menu like facebook notification menu. But i have one problem with javascript code.

This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/jYeL9/) example . My problem is when i click  menu will open but menu has a icon for example like facebook. Facebok notification when you click notification menu icon is automatically white but when you click other area icon is different color. I want only background color will be change. but if you check this link you can understand What is my problem. 
**This is my HTML Code :**

```
<div class="msdv">
    <a class="account"><span></span></a>

<div class="bubble">
       <div class="xstr"><div class="gks">lorem</div><div class="yms">lorem</div></div>
       <div class="xstrs">
     <ul class="root">
         <li><a href="#mesajınızvar" role="button">
         <div class="usrxmsg">
           <div class="xtreaimage"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5/1115776_100001145177906_1788754675_q.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
           <div class="msinf">
           <div class="msisndoknk">
           <div class="msis">lorem</div>
           <div class="msisok"></div>
           </div>
             <div class="mxsg">loremloremloremloremloremlorem</div>
             <div class="msdtm">14:38</div>
           </div>

         </div></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#mesajınızvar" role="button">
         <div class="usrxmsg">
           <div class="xtreaimage"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5/1115776_100001145177906_1788754675_q.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
           <div class="msinf">
           <div class="msisndoknk">
           <div class="msis">loremloremlorem</div>
           <div class="msisok"></div>
           </div>
             <div class="mxsg">loremloremloremloremloremloremlorem.</div>
             <div class="msdtm">14:38</div>
           </div>

         </div></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#mesajınızvar" role="button">
         <div class="usrxmsg">
           <div class="xtreaimage"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5/1115776_100001145177906_1788754675_q.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
           <div class="msinf">
           <div class="msisndoknk">
           <div class="msis">loremloremloremlorem</div>
           <div class="msisok"></div>
           </div>
             <div class="mxsg">loremloremloremloremloremloremlorem</div>
             <div class="msdtm">14:38</div>
           </div>

         </div></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#mesajınızvar" role="button">
         <div class="usrxmsg">
           <div class="xtreaimage"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5/1115776_100001145177906_1788754675_q.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
           <div class="msinf">
           <div class="msisndoknk">
           <div class="msis">loremloremloremloremlorem</div>
           <div class="msisok"></div>
           </div>
             <div class="mxsg">lorem</div>
             <div class="msdtm">14:38</div>
           </div>

         </div></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#mesajınızvar" role="button">
         <div class="usrxmsg">
           <div class="xtreaimage"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5/1115776_100001145177906_1788754675_q.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
           <div class="msinf">
           <div class="msisndoknk">
           <div class="msis">loremloremloremloremlorem</div>
           <div class="msisok"></div>
           </div>
             <div class="mxsg">loremloremloremloremlorem</div>
             <div class="msdtm">14:38</div>
           </div>

         </div></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#mesajınızvar" role="button">
         <div class="usrxmsg">
           <div class="xtreaimage"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5/1115776_100001145177906_1788754675_q.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
           <div class="msinf">
           <div class="msisndoknk">
           <div class="msis">loremlorem</div>
           <div class="msisok"></div>
           </div>
             <div class="mxsg">loremloremloremloremloremloremloremlorem</div>
             <div class="msdtm">14:38</div>
           </div>

         </div></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#mesajınızvar" role="button">
         <div class="usrxmsg">
           <div class="xtreaimage"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5/1115776_100001145177906_1788754675_q.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
           <div class="msinf">
           <div class="msisndoknk">
           <div class="msis">loremloremloremloremlorem</div>
           <div class="msisok"></div>
           </div>
             <div class="mxsg">loremloremloremloremloremloremloremlorem</div>
             <div class="msdtm">14:38</div>
           </div>

         </div></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#mesajınızvar" role="button">
         <div class="usrxmsg">
           <div class="xtreaimage"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5/1115776_100001145177906_1788754675_q.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
           <div class="msinf">
           <div class="msisndoknk">
           <div class="msis">loremloremlorem</div>
           <div class="msisok"></div>
           </div>
             <div class="mxsg">loremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremloremlorem</div>
             <div class="msdtm">14:38</div>
           </div>

         </div></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#mesajınızvar" role="button">
         <div class="usrxmsg">
           <div class="xtreaimage"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5/1115776_100001145177906_1788754675_q.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
           <div class="msinf">
           <div class="msisndoknk">
           <div class="msis">loremloremlorem</div>
           <div class="msisok"></div>
           </div>
             <div class="mxsg">loremlorem</div>
             <div class="msdtm">14:38</div>
           </div>

         </div></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#mesajınızvar" role="button">
         <div class="usrxmsg">
           <div class="xtreaimage"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5/1115776_100001145177906_1788754675_q.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
           <div class="msinf">
           <div class="msisndoknk">
           <div class="msis">loremloremlorem</div>
           <div class="msisok"></div>
           </div>
             <div class="mxsg">lorem</div>
             <div class="msdtm">14:38</div>
           </div>

         </div></a>
         </li>

    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="xstrdob">loremloremlorem</div>

</div>
</div>
```

**And also this is my Css code:**

```
.msdv {
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#2a3542;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
    margin-left:130px;
}
.bubble 
{
    float:left;
position: relative;
width: 330px;
height: auto;
padding: 0px;
border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
background: #f4f4f4;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:-87px;
    display:none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 16px 0px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.47);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 16px 0px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.47);
box-shadow:         0px 10px 16px 0px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.47);
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 15px 15px;
border-color: #e7eaee transparent;
display: block;

width: 0;
z-index: 1;
top: -14px;
left: 134px;

}
.bubble:before 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 15px 15px;
border-color: #d8dbdf transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
top: -15px;
left: 134px;

}

.msdv ul li a {
    width:325px;
    height:50px;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px 2px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d8dbdf;
}
.msdv ul li a:hover {
    background:#edeff4;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a.account {
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 40px;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
z-index: 110;
display: block;
padding: 11px 0 0 20px;
height: 28px;
width: 121px;
margin: -11px 0 0 -10px;
text-decoration: none;
background: url(../icons/arrow3.png) 1px 9px no-repeat;

cursor:pointer;
}

.root
{
list-style:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-size: 11px;
padding: 1px 0 0 0px;
border-top:1px solid #d8dbdf;


}
.xstr {
    background:#e7eaee;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px solid #d8dbdf;
    text-align:left;
    color:#333333;
    text-indent:7px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12px;
    }
.bubble.xstr {
    width:285px;
    height:5px;
    text-align:left;
    }
.gks {
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    width:135px;
    }
.bubble.gks{
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;

    }
.yms{
    float:right;
    color:#4e69a2;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:35px;
    width:150px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:normal;
    }
.xstr.yms{
    float:left;

    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;

    }
.xstrdob{
    background:#e7eaee;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    border: 0px solid #d8dbdf;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -3px 2px 0px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.14);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px -3px 2px 0px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.14);
    box-shadow:         0px -3px 2px 0px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.14);
    color:#3b5998;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
.bubble.xstrdob{
   width:285px;
   margin: 0 auto;

    }
.xstrs{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:400px;
    }
.bubble.xstrs {
    float:left;
    width:280px;
    }
.bubble.xstrs::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.bubble.xstrs::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.bubble.xstrs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #555;
}
.usrxmsg{
    float:left;
    width:315px;
    height:50px;
    }
.xtreaimage{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#0000;
    }
.msinf{
    float:left;
    width:265px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:left;
    }
.msisndoknk{
    float:left;
    width:265px;
    height:15px;
    }
.msis{
    float:left;
    width:252px;
    height:15px;
    color:#333333;
    line-height:15px;
    text-indent:10px;

    }
.msisok{
    float:left;
    width:13px;
    height:15px;
    background-image:url(../icons/okundu.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
.mxsg{
    float:left;
    width:265px;
    height:18px;
    text-indent:10px;
    line-height:18px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#808080;
}
.msdtm{
    float:left;
    width:265px;
    height:18px;
    text-indent:10px;
    line-height:18px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#808080;
    }
.msdv.open .account { 
                cursor: pointer;
                width: auto;
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 7px;
                padding-top: 4px;
                padding-bottom: 4px;
                padding-right: 22px;
                border: 1px solid #AAA;
                -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
                -moz-border-radius: 2px;
                border-radius: 2px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #717780;
                line-height: 16px;
                text-decoration: none !important;
                background: white url("http://ttb.li/dump/buttons/dropdown_arrow.png") no-repeat 100% 0px;
            }
            .msdv.open .account {
                border: 1px solid #3B5998;
                color: white;
                background: #6D84B4 url("http://ttb.li/dump/buttons/dropdown_arrow.png") no-repeat 100% -26px;
                -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
                border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
                border-bottom-color: #6D84B4;
            }
            .msdv .account img {
                height: 14px; 
                margin-top: 1px;
                margin-bottom: 1px;
                float: left; 
                margin-right: 5px; 
            }
```

**and the last time javascript function code is here:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".account").click(function()
{
var X=$(this).attr('id');

if(X==1)
{
$(".bubble").hide();
$(this).attr('id', '0');    
}
else
{

$(".bubble").show();
$(this).attr('id', '1');
}

});

//Mouseup textarea false
$(".bubble").mouseup(function()
{
return false
});
$(".account").mouseup(function()
{
return false
});


//Textarea without editing.
$(document).mouseup(function()
{
$(".bubble").hide();
$(".account").attr('id', '');
});


    $(function(){
                $('.msdv').each(function(){
                    $(this).find('.account').bind('click',function(){
                        if($(this).parent().hasClass('open')){
                            $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
                        }else{
                            $('.account.open').removeClass('open');
                            $(this).parent().addClass('open');
                        }
                    });    
                });
                $('.msdv li').each(function(){
                    $(this).bind('click',function(){  
                        $('.account.open').removeClass('open');
                    });
                });
                $(document).on('click', function(e) {
                    var $clicked = $(e.target);
                    if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("msdv")){
                        $('.account.open').removeClass('open');
                    }
                });
            });
    });
```

Comment: Can you add some clarity to your question. Is the problem when you click your icon to open the menu you want that icon to change colour? Or is that when the menu is open you want those pictures on the left to change colour?

Comment: @jjay225 I want to change background color. When i click. If you check my JSFiddle my color is working. But when i click other area last color does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified your jsfiddle to get a better understanding of it. In this fiddle if you click on the icon it brings up the menu and if you click on the background or the icon again it will disappear. Is this what you wanted?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jYeL9/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".account").click(function()
{
    if($(".bubble").css('display')=='none')
    {
        $(".msdv").addClass('open');
        $(".bubble").css('display','block');


    }
    else
    {
         $(".bubble").css('display','none');
         $(".msdv").removeClass('open');

    }

});
$(document).click(function(e)
{
  if($(e.target).attr('class')!='account')
  {

    if($(".bubble").css('display')=='block')
    {
        if($('.msdv').hasClass('open'))
          {
              $('.msdv').removeClass('open');
          }
          $(".bubble").css('display','none');
     }
   }
});

 });
```

Comment: this is ok now. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `$('.msdv').removeClass("open");` to the end of your document click event like so:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("msdv")){
         $('.account.open').removeClass('open');
         $('.msdv').removeClass("open");
    }
});
```

Comment: Dear problem again. This code working in JSFiddle but not working in localhost. Whats wrong i don't understand ?

Comment: Might be a cache or local environment issue, make sure all file contents is correct and uncached

Comment: When I click with the mouse to the menu. color changing menu and the menu is opened. But when I click on a different area of the color-changing menu remains the same.

Comment: Is there any difference between the JSFiddle code and your local code? If so, please explain what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the css code here try this.

```
.msdv {
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#2a3542;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;

}
.bubble 
{
    float:left;
position: relative;
width: 330px;
height: auto;
padding: 0px;
border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
background: #f4f4f4;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:-87px;
    display:none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 16px 0px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.47);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 16px 0px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.47);
box-shadow:         0px 10px 16px 0px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.47);
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 15px 15px;
border-color: #e7eaee transparent;
display: block;

width: 0;
z-index: 1;
top: -14px;
left: 134px;

}
.bubble:before 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 15px 15px;
border-color: #d8dbdf transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
top: -15px;
left: 134px;

}

.msdv ul li a {
    width:325px;
    height:50px;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px 2px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d8dbdf;
}
.msdv ul li a:hover {
    background:#edeff4;
    color:#000000;

}
a.account {
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 40px;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
z-index: 110;
display: block;
padding: 11px 0 0 20px;
height: 28px;
width: 121px;
margin: -11px 0 0 -10px;
text-decoration: none;
background: url(../icons/arrow3.png) 1px 9px no-repeat;

cursor:pointer;
}

.root
{
list-style:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-size: 11px;
padding: 1px 0 0 0px;
border-top:1px solid #d8dbdf;


}
.xstr {
    background:#e7eaee;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px solid #d8dbdf;
    text-align:left;
    color:#333333;
    text-indent:7px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12px;
    }
.bubble.xstr {
    width:285px;
    height:5px;
    text-align:left;
    }
.gks {
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    width:135px;
    }
.bubble.gks{
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;

    }
.yms{
    float:right;
    color:#4e69a2;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:35px;
    width:150px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:normal;
    }
.xstr.yms{
    float:left;

    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;

    }
.xstrdob{
    background:#e7eaee;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    border: 0px solid #d8dbdf;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -3px 2px 0px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.14);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px -3px 2px 0px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.14);
    box-shadow:         0px -3px 2px 0px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.14);
    color:#3b5998;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
.bubble.xstrdob{
   width:285px;
   margin: 0 auto;

    }
.xstrs{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:400px;
    }
.bubble.xstrs {
    float:left;
    width:280px;
    }
.bubble.xstrs::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.bubble.xstrs::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.bubble.xstrs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #555;
}
.usrxmsg{
    float:left;
    width:315px;
    height:50px;
    }
.xtreaimage{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#0000;
    }
.msinf{
    float:left;
    width:265px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:left;
    }
.msisndoknk{
    float:left;
    width:265px;
    height:15px;
    }
.msis{
    float:left;
    width:252px;
    height:15px;
    color:#333333;
    line-height:15px;
    text-indent:10px;

    }
.msisok{
    float:left;
    width:13px;
    height:15px;
    background-image:url(../icons/okundu.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
.mxsg{
    float:left;
    width:265px;
    height:18px;
    text-indent:10px;
    line-height:18px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#808080;
}
.msdtm{
    float:left;
    width:265px;
    height:18px;
    text-indent:10px;
    line-height:18px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#808080;
    }
.msdv.open .account { 
                cursor: pointer;
                width: auto;
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 7px;
                padding-top: 4px;
                padding-bottom: 4px;
                padding-right: 22px;
                border: 1px solid #AAA;
                -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
                -moz-border-radius: 2px;
                border-radius: 2px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #717780;
                line-height: 16px;
                text-decoration: none !important;
                background: white url("http://ttb.li/dump/buttons/dropdown_arrow.png") no-repeat 100% 0px;
            }
            .msdv.open .account {
                border: 1px solid #3B5998;
                color: white;
                background: #6D84B4 url("http://ttb.li/dump/buttons/dropdown_arrow.png") no-repeat 100% -26px;
                -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
                border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
                border-bottom-color: #6D84B4;
            }
            .msdv .account img {
                height: 14px; 
                margin-top: 1px;
                margin-bottom: 1px;
                float: left; 
                margin-right: 5px; 
            }
```

I am sure other formatting you can do.Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: my problem not in css. When I click with the mouse to the menu. color changing menu and the menu is opened. But when I click on a different area of the color-changing menu remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

For me, replacing
`$('.account.open').removeClass('open');`
with `$('.msdv').removeClass("open");`
is enough :

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
   var $clicked = $(e.target);
   if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("msdv")){
       $('.msdv').removeClass("open");
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not solution mr @Brice